# Error when migrate data in data migration of magento 2

Tags: magento2, wishlist

I have this error, "Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '3841' for key 'WISHLIST_CUSTOMER_ID'"

Comment: when does this error occure? are you executing a CLI command?

Comment: @PhilippSander which CLI command

Comment: that's something i asked you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will empty magento 1 wishlist table and it works fine. Thank you for reply.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the duplicate entry from wishlist table and try again. it should work.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the duplicate entry!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/179372)

Comment: @HelgeB got it! Thank you for your reminder!